# How to create custom route to a page in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, redirect, routes

I want to set a new Route in WordPress that will be redirected to the desired path by entering a specific pattern.

for example:
When I enter any url like below:

```
http://mywebsite.com/audio/Everything

http://mywebsite.com/audio/**********

http://mywebsite.com/audio/0123456789
```

These routes and similar ones redirects to sound.php

```
http://mywebsite.com/wp-content/sounds/sound.php
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **add_rewrite_rule** function, Here is official WP reference - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_rule/

As per your example above, You can do like below,

```
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
function custom_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^audio/([^/]*)/?','wp-content/sounds/sound.php','top');
}
```

1. Try above code as per your requirement and add into your theme's
   function.php OR plugin file.
2. After code added, You must Go to **Settings** > **Permalinks** page on your site admin panel and do click on **Save Changes** button.

Comment: Thank you very mach. It was a great help.